# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente message de cada una de las líneas donde me sale el error voy a poner el código, no he podido ver donde esta el error

```
   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   en Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
   en XML.ConsultaPlacas.<ConsultarPLaca>d__0.MoveNext() en C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Documentos\Archivos\IntegracionCloudFleet\PruebaConceptoIntegracionCompras\XML\ConsultaPlacas.cs: línea 22
```

```
  public async Task<Placas> ConsultarPLaca(Vehiculos detalle)
            {
                using (WSSincronizacionClient clienteSAP = new WSSincronizacionClient())
                {
                    string XmlSerializado = this.SerializarXml(detalle);
                    var respuesta = await clienteSAP.ConsultarDatosSAPAsync(XmlSerializado);
   Linea 22 ------->var ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Placas>> (respuesta);
                    return ob?.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
```

```
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en BusinessLogic.ProxyBL.<ConsultarPlaca>d__2.MoveNext() en C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Documentos\Archivos\IntegracionCloudFleet\PruebaConceptoIntegracionCompras\BusinessLogic\ProxyBL.cs: línea 71
```

```
  public async Task<Placas> ConsultarPlaca(Vehiculos detalle)
            {
                ConsultaPlacas xmlProxy = new ConsultaPlacas();
Linea 71 -----> Placas respuesta = await xmlProxy.ConsultarPLaca(detalle);
                return respuesta;
            }
```

```
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en Presentation.MainCompras.<Envio1>d__13.MoveNext() en C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Documentos\Archivos\IntegracionCloudFleet\PruebaConceptoIntegracionCompras\Presentation\MainCompras.cs: línea 257
```

```
    private async void Envio1(int id) {#region Ejecucion Manual Envio
      Consultas c = new Consultas();
      Vehiculos obtenerDatosCloudFleet = null;
      Jobs obtenerDatosCloudFleetDetalle = new Jobs();
      List < Jobs > detallesJobs = null;
      ProxyBL proxy = new ProxyBL();
      try {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow encabezado in dataGridView2.Rows) {
    
          if (Convert.ToInt32(encabezado.Cells[0].Value) == id) {
            obtenerDatosCloudFleet = new Vehiculos() {
              number = Convert.ToInt32(encabezado.Cells[0].Value),
              vehicleCode = Convert.ToString(encabezado.Cells[1].Value),
              Email = Convert.ToString(encabezado.Cells[13].Value),
              Name = Convert.ToString(encabezado.Cells[11].Value),
              estimatedFinishDate = Convert.ToDateTime(encabezado.Cells[5].Value),
              startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(encabezado.Cells[6].Value),
              comments = Convert.ToString(encabezado.Cells[14].Value),
            };
    
            detallesJobs = new List < Jobs > ();
            foreach(DataGridViewRow detalle in dataGridView2.Rows) {
              if (Convert.ToInt32(detalle.Cells[0].Value) == id) {
                if (Convert.ToString(detalle.Cells[16].Value) == obtenerDatosCloudFleet.number.ToString()) {
                  var jobs = new Jobs() {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(detalle.Cells[17].Value),
                    name = Convert.ToString(detalle.Cells[18].Value),
                    identificador = Convert.ToString(detalle.Cells[23].Value),
    
                  };
                  detallesJobs.Add(jobs);
                }
              }
            }
Linea 257   -->  var ConDatos = await proxy.ConsultarPlaca(obtenerDatosCloudFleet);
            var ConDocNum = await proxy.ConsultarDoc(obtenerDatosCloudFleet);
            Number = obtenerDatosCloudFleet.number.ToString();
            ConsultaDeFilas Cons = c.ListarEnvioFilas(Convert.ToString(Number));
            List < int > idNum = new List < int > () {
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5
            };
            if (idNum.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(encabezado.Cells[22].Value))) {
              if (Cons.FilasEncero == 0) {
                var envio = await proxy.EnviarPedidoL(obtenerDatosCloudFleet, detallesJobs);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ListarLog();
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "Encabezado");
      }
```

Objetos  placas

```
public  class Placas
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string U_AcctCode { get; set; }
        public string U_OcrCode { get; set; }
        public string DimCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Valor de la variable  respuesta

```
[{"Code":"51","U_AcctCode":"73454001","U_OcrCode":"1704","DimCode":1}]
```

Comment: Hola @hackerman, nos puedes pegar el valor de la variable respuesta? Imagino que no será una cadena Json válida

Comment: Si ya la puse en la pregunta

Comment: Mmm no se si tenga que ver, pero el tipo de dato de DimCode no coincide. En la entidad es de tipo string, pero en el JSON que muestras es un entero.

Answer (score 2):

El problema indica que no puede deserializar la respuesta a un objeto correctamente.

De acuerdo a tu respuesta:

```
[{"Code":"51","U_AcctCode":"73454001","U_OcrCode":"1704","DimCode":1}]
```

puedes generar tu objeto a partir de la respuesta de la siguiente forma:

```
    //var ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Placas>> (respuesta);
    var ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(respuesta);
    //Comprueba valores en objeto
    foreach (dynamic elemento in ob)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Code: " + elemento.Code + " - U_AcctCode: " + elemento.U_AcctCode + " - U_OcrCode: " + elemento.U_OcrCode + " - DimCode: " + elemento.DimCode);
    }
```

si compruebas los valores que se almacenan en el objeto obtendrías:

```
Code: 51 - U_AcctCode: 73454001 - U_OcrCode: 1704 - DimCode: 1
```

---

Actualización:

Al revisar tu código serializas en un objeto Placas, este debe cambiar a:

```
public class Placas
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string U_AcctCode { get; set; }
    public string U_OcrCode { get; set; }
    public int DimCode { get; set; }
}
```

Para de esta forma poder deserealizar adecuadamente de acuerdo a la respuesta:

```
var ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Placas>> (respuesta);
```

Comment: no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'system.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' en 'BussinesObjects.Placas.Placas '  Me sale esto en el -->  return ob?.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo veo que el método retorna "Placas", eres la misma persona que pregunta?

Comment: Sii, es que no me fije y respondí desde otro equipo.

Comment: Gracias @EstebanGiraldo , de hecho veo que ya agregaste tu objeto Placas, voy a editar esa parte de la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas  Gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo primero cambia el tipo por favor de DimCode en tu objeto Placas y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: @Hackerman creo que fue injusto haberle dado la recompensa a Jorgesys puesto que la primera respuesta válida fue la mía, jorge edito la suya posterior a la mia  para incluir el cambio en el tipo de objeto que había comentado yo antes, un saludo.

Comment: Si, es verdad pero igual esta solución no me ayudo,  me sigue saliendo lo mismo saludos

Comment: Agrega que error esta mostrandose por favor @Hackerman

Answer (score -1):

la propiedad DimCode del objeto Placas la declaras como string pero en tu json de respuesta la tienes como entera.

Para corregirla solo tienes que cambiar a esto:

```
public  class Placas
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string U_AcctCode { get; set; }
        public string U_OcrCode { get; set; }
        public int DimCode { get; set; }
    }
```